# GoLang conventions - create custom type from slice

Tags: go, conventions, convention

Is it a good idea to create own type from a slice in Golang?

Example:

```
type Trip struct {
    From   string
    To     string
    Length int
}

type Trips []Trip // <-- is this a good idea?

func (trips *Trips) TotalLength() int {
    ret := 0
    for _, i := range *trips {
        ret += i.Length
    }

    return ret
}
```

Is it somehow a convention in Golang to create types like `Trips` in my example? Or it is better to use `[]Trip` in the whole project? Any pros and cons?

Comment: Yes,if you will understand that such Trips. Experts recommend to name the types in the context of the problem being solved.

Answer (score 17):

There's no convention, as far as I am aware of. It's OK to create a slice type if you really need it. In fact, if you ever want to sort your data, this is pretty much the only way: create a type and define the [`sort.Interface`](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) methods on it.

Also, in your example there is no need to take the address of `Trips` since slice is already a "fat pointer" of a kind. So you can simplify your method to:

```
func (trips Trips) TotalLength() (tl int) {
    for _, l := range trips {
        tl += l.Length
    }
    return tl
}
```

Comment: In this case we could just write that method in one line as `func (trips Trips) TotalLenght() int {return len(trips)}`

Answer (score 8):

If this is what your type is (a slice), it's just fine. It gives you an easy access to underlying elements (and allows for `range` iteration) while providing additional methods.

Of course you probably should only keep *essential* set of methods on this type and not bloating it with everything that would take `[]Trip` as an argument. (For example I would suggest having `DrawTripsOnTheGlobe(t Trips)` rather than having it as a Trips' method.)

To calm your mind there are plenty of such slice-types in standard packages:

http://golang.org/pkg/net/#IP

http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Float64Slice

http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#IntSlice

http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage